Creating a recordset inside a sub/function
I want to create a recordset in MS Access inside a sub, once created the same recordset should be available outside the sub. What I came up with is the following
Public Sub CustomerListRst(ByRef Rst As Variant)
    If Not IsNull(Rst) Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Rst.Close
        Set Rst = Nothing
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
    Set Rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from Tbl_xxxx")
End Sub

the recordset is created and allocated to Rst but when the process goes back from the point where the sub was called then rst becomes empty, despite I set ByRef Rst
What am I doing wrong ?

Is Rst nothing or simply pointing to an empty recordset? How many records do you have in Tbl_xxxx? Maybe check the value of Rst before you leave the procedure.

I suggest you use Rst Is Nothing instead of IsNull(Rst)

I would use a strong type for the recordset: ByRef Rst As Recordset. You can also specify the library : DAO.Recordet or ADODB.Record. Variant should only be used when different types must be assigned to the same variable or when a value type like Long can be Null when returned from a database.

The problem may arise from using CurrentDb. . To create a recordset that survives the procedure, you may need a public DB variable from which you open the recordset.

Addition to @Andre's comment: Pass the db to the sub and use the same db in the caller : Public Sub CustomerListRst(ByVal db As Database, ByRef Rst As Recordset). Use Set db = CurrentDb in the caller and use it there to create the recordset and to call CustomerListRst, because the CurrentDb function always returns another db object.

Should probably edit question to show calling procedure as well.

You must specify the recordset object first:
Public Function MyTest()

    Dim Rst As DAO.Recordset

    CustomerListRst Rst
    Debug.Print Rst.RecordCount

    CustomerListRst Rst
    If Rst.RecordCount > 0 Then
        Rst.MoveLast
    End If
    Debug.Print Rst.RecordCount

End Function


Public Sub CustomerListRst(ByRef Rst As DAO.Recordset)

    If Not Rst Is Nothing Then
        Rst.Close
        Set Rst = Nothing
    End If

    Set Rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from Tbl_xxxx")

End Sub


You can check with "Dim Rst As Object" as well. This should preserve.

But why, when there’s a specific data type available here?

Here is the solution that works for me.
It was necessary to have a stronger type definition of the record. Here is what it is working for me.
Note that Call needs to be used otherwise, it fails
Dim Rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim cls As clsCustomerList
Set cls = New clsCustomerList
Call cls.CustomerListRst (Rst)

...
Public Sub CustomerListRst(ByRef Rst As DAO.Recordset)
'    Public Sub CustomerListRst(ByVal db As Database, ByRef Rst As DAO.Recordset)
    If Not Rst Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Rst.Close
        Set Rst = Nothing
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
    Set Rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from Tbl_CustomersList")
End Sub

in this case, once the control returns to the main program, Rst still holds the data.
